# '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER]'

Tags: python, ssl, hadoop, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to connect google api from jupyter notebook which is installed in hadoop cluster.
While connecting to api via proxy, i am getting the below error:

HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1091)')))

Note: Python version - 2.7.18

code snippet:
os.environ['http_proxy'] = "http://username:pwd@host:port"
os.environ['https_proxy'] = "https://username:pwd@host:port"

Tried to connect by specifying the specific version of ssl in the code,but that didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This error has most times nothing to do with an actual wrong TLS version, but with a non-TLS response from the target interpreted as TLS. This might be due to something intercepting the traffic. Or it might be a wrong proxy specification. Too much unknown here.